# How do Spring (Boot) specifications work when I need joins on multiple occasions?

Tags: java, spring-boot, jpa, criteria, specifications

so I have an SQL query like:

```
SELECT stuff
FROM a
  JOIN x ON a.id = x.a_id
  JOIN (SELECT ... FROM a join b ON ...) as foo
  WHERE foo.c = 'bar'
  AND foo.d = true
  AND ...
```

Though I want to convert that to Java code using, for example, Spring Specifications. I know how to use them in general but I've read, for example, that subqueries are only allowed in the WHERE part? Is that right?

But nonetheless: how would I make that SQL query in Specifications? So far I've used a special Specification class where I do stuff like:

```
public static Specification<Foo> hasStuff(long stuffId) {
        return (root, criteriaQuery, criteriaBuilder) -> criteriaBuilder.equal(root.get(Foo_.stuff), stuffId);
}
```

But this wouldn't work for more complex situations, right? Cause if I split up the line with
`foo.c = 'bar'`
and
`foo.d = true`
into different methods, I would do the join twice, right?

Edit: Oh right, and another important thing. If I want to aggregate all the checks of the WHERE, how can I do that? Previously I just created a `List<Specification<SomeClass>>` but since I now need to use joins, I can't just put SomeClass in the generics since my result will be arbitrary.

Answer (score 0):

You can use **`nativeQuery = true parameter to the @Query`**.

If you don't add the `nativeQuery = true` parameter to the `@Query` annotation in a Spring Repository, the query will be considered as written in JPQL.

```
  @Query(
  value = "SELECT stuff
           FROM a
           JOIN x ON a.id = x.a_id
           JOIN (SELECT ... FROM a join b ON ...) as foo
           WHERE foo.c = 'bar'
           AND foo.d = true
           AND ...", 
  nativeQuery = true)
Collection<Entity> findAllRecords();
```

From the JPQL you can check [here](https://openjpa.apache.org/builds/1.2.3/apache-openjpa/docs/jpa_langref.html#jpa_langref_subqueries):

> Subqueries may be used in the WHERE or HAVING clause.

So add natuveQuery attribute with **`true`** value. It will help you.

Comment: I know I could use `@Query` but I'm not using it since this is a dynamic query that's built up depending on like 10 different filter settings. I I'd use `@Query` I'd have a massive query even if no filters were set. That's why I use Specifications.